# Destroy a tk.Frame from a class that inherits from tk.Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, refresh, destroy

I am trying to develop a program based on a calendar. In my calendar, every day of the month is a button and I can store information in it. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

kalender =  tk.Tk()
kalender.title("Overtime Tracker")
kalender.resizable(0, 0)

year = int(str(datetime.datetime.now())[0:4])
month = int(str(datetime.datetime.now())[6:7])

monthmatrix = calendar.monthcalendar(year,month)

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, kalender, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.createwidgets()

    def createwidgets(self):
        <all the widgets I need for my GUI>

class Application (GUI):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.year = year    
        self.month = month
        self.monthmatrix = monthmatrix 
        GUI.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.previousmonth = tk.Button(self, font=("Helvetica", 15), text= "<", command=lambda: self.PrevMonth())
        self.previousmonth.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NWNESWSE")
        self.nextmonth = tk.Button(self, font=("Helvetica", 15), text= ">", command=lambda: self.NextMonth())
        self.nextmonth.grid(row=0, column=7, sticky="NWNESWSE")

    def PrevMonth(self):
        self.month = self.month-1
        self.monthmatrix = calendar.monthcalendar(self.year,self.month)
        GUI.destroy(self)
        GUI.__init__(self, kalender)


    def NextMonth(self):
        self.year = year
        self.month = self.month+1
        self.monthmatrix = calendar.monthcalendar(self.year,self.month)
        GUI.destroy(self)
        GUI.__init__(self, kalender)

app = Application(kalender).grid()     
kalender.mainloop()
```

The application itself is another class that inherits from GUI and features all the other functions to which the buttons of the GUI are connected, etc.

The thing is that the two buttons "self.previousmonth" and "self.nextmonth", which are located in the application class and not in the GUI, are supoosed to be there for browsing the months. Thus, my idea was to shift the month value +1 or -1 (depending on the button), remove the tk.Frame, and open the GUI again with the new month.

Internally, everything works fine, the arrays and everything the program works with switch properly to the corresponding to the month before/after, but the calendar of the corresponding month doesn't appear. Instead, the frame is removed along with all the widgets (I guess it is what happens. What can be seen is that the window in which the program was empties completely), but the next month doesnt appear. The window just stays empty. Besides that, the console does not yield any error.

First, I am not sure I am destroying the tk.Frame properly, although this is what visually seems to happen. In order to be sure I have tried to structure the GUI like:

```
kalender = tk.Tk()

class GUI():
    def __init__(self, kalender):
        self.kalender = kalender
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.kalender)
```

But then, obviously, the class Application does not have the tk attributes that it needs.

On the other side, it could be that, after properly destroying the tk.Frame, I am somehow doing a mistake in calling the GUI again.

Can someone spot the problem?

### Edit after Brian's comment

I put here a simplified version of the problem:

```
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

kalender =  tk.Tk()

year = int(str(datetime.datetime.now())[0:4]) # takes the year from datetime
month = int(str(datetime.datetime.now())[6:7]) # takes the month from datetime

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, kalender, *args, **kwargs):
        self.kalender = kalender
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.createwidgets()

    def createwidgets(self):
        self.kalendertitle = tk.Label(self, text=str(calendar.month_name[self.month])+" "+str(year)).grid(row=0, column=1)

class Application (GUI):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.year = year    
        self.month = month
        GUI.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.nextmonth = tk.Button(self, text= ">", command=lambda: self.NextMonth())
        self.nextmonth.grid(row=0, column=7)

    def NextMonth(self):
        self.year = year
        self.month = self.month+1
        GUI.destroy(self)
        GUI.__init__(self, kalender)

app = Application(kalender).grid()     
kalender.mainloop()
```

The year and the month are take read from datetime. Class GUI initializes and calls the function "createwidgets", which in this case displays just the current month and year. The application comes as another class that inherits from GUI. It also incorporates a button to switch to the next month. This is done via the function "NextMonth". The idea of the function is to increase the month index, destroy the GUI and retrieve it again with the month index one unit larger, i.e. the display should show "July 2017".

As mentioned before, either the destruction of the frame doesn't work or the retrieval of the GUI is not properly passed. The window in which the GUI was empties completely (which makes me think the "destroy" function works properly). The console does not give any error.

Comment: please create a [mcve] I see imports and many lines of code that seem unrelated to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

The problem was, mainly, that I was creating the widgets as follows:

```
self.randomWidget = tk.Widget(self, ....)
```

This means that the destruction of the frame and its new retrieval was working. But since the widgets were not IN the frame, nothing happened visually.

I eventually solved the problem by doing something like:

```
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

year = int(str(datetime.datetime.now())[0:4]) # takes the year from datetime
month = int(str(datetime.datetime.now())[6:7]) # takes the month from datetime

class GUI():
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.createwidgets()

    def createwidgets(self):
        self.kalendertitle = tk.Label(self.frame, text=str(calendar.month_name[self.month])+" "+str(self.year))
        self.kalendertitle.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.nextmonth = tk.Button(self.frame, text= ">", command=lambda: self.NextMonth())
        self.nextmonth.grid(row=0, column=7)

class Application (GUI):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        self.year = year    
        self.month = month
        GUI.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

    def NextMonth(self):
        self.month = self.month+1
        self.frame.destroy()
        GUI.__init__(self, root)


root =  tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

As you see, I needed as well to pass "master", or root, which was previously not there (and I believe it is per default "None"). It is yet not clear to me how much part of the original problem this missing "master" was.

The widgets inserted in the "self.frame" makes the whole thing work properly. And another bad idea of the code before was putting the browsing buttons in the Application and not in the GUI. Because, of course, after the first frame refreshing the buttons were gone.

The whole thing I did by making the GUI class NOT to inherit from tk.Frame. I have researched a little bit on that and didn´t find major arguments for one or the other options besides esthetics and code readability (which is also important).